# Specify max number of items in a class when using train_test_split from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

I am working with a highly imbalanced dataset and using train_test_split from `sklearn.model_selection`

I have 10000 items in this dataset and the ratio is about 10/2/2/1 for the classes, what I am looking for is a way to have the `train` split balanced 
and I would like to stop adding elements to the largest class when it reaches a max number.

Is it possible to limit the number of items, I know is possible to remove the extra items after splitting but I wonder if there is such an option?

Answer (score 0):

Use `stratify` parameter while calling `train_test_split` function. Follow the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for more info.

For 30% test data, you can do like this

`X_train,X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, y_true, stratify=y_true, test_size=0.3)`

`data` is your total data & `y_true` is your ground truth values

Comment: To complement Kalsi's anwser: stratification means splitting a dataset evenly by class. It gives you a test dataset that has the same proportion of each class as the original dataset.

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what I am looking for, I want to stop adding elements to `x_train` when it reaches a certain max number, I don't care for `x_test`, I want to do this to give the smaller classes a fighting chance in the classifier.